# Windows Service not starting in a timely manner - pass off initial workload to timer?

Tags: c#, .net, service, timer, windows-services

I'm running a Windows Service which does a large data migration process (will take 10 minutes+ on first run through). Currently I have the service running once initially on startup, and then every 4 hours thereafter. Something like this (excerpt):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Set up timer
    int intervalSync = 14400; // 4 hours default
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = intervalSync * 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
    timer.Start();

    // Call once initially.
    this.DoMigration();
}

public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    this.DoMigration();
}
```

The problem is after deploying and running, the Windows Service errors with "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion".

I realise I could just remove the initial call of DoMigration() from OnStart, and let the service start up quickly - but then the work would not be done for 4 hours which is not desirable.

Is there a way I can set a different time interval for the first timer to run (perhaps 30 seconds or 60 seconds), and then the separate 4 hour periodic interval after that? Basically I want to push the workload out of OnStart to prevent the error, but I want to still have it run as soon as possible after starting.

Is this possible? And is it the best approach? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Set off another timer with an interval of a few seconds to do the data migration.

Comment: Why not use a background thread for the data migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `OnStart` method needs to complete in a fairly short time (30 seconds perhaps?) before Windows assumes something has gone wrong. A simple solution would be to fire the timer very quickly on it's first run, the reconfigure the timer from inside the event to run again in 4 hours:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Set up timer
    int initialIntervalSync = 10; // 10 seconds
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = initialIntervalSync * 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
    timer.Start();    
}

public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    //Reset timer interval
    int intervalSync = 14400; // 4 hours default
    timer.Interval = intervalSync * 1000;

    this.DoMigration();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the easiest way to address this is to use `async`/`await`:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Storing the returned Task in a variable is a hack
    // to suppresses the usual compiler warning.
    var _ = DoMigrationLoop();
}

private async Task DoMigrationLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => this.DoMigration());
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(4));
    }
}
```

This causes the `DoMigration()` method to be executed in a separate thread immediately, and then every four hours thereafter. Note that since the original `DoMigrationLoop()` method call returns immediately at the first `await` call, the `OnStart()` method is itself not delayed at all.

Feel free to add task cancellation, exception handling, and other niceties as desired. :)